# code for Garsia-Milne bijection

Tags: partitions

The combinatorial interpretation of the first Rogers-Ramanujan identity states that the partitions of n with gaps at least two between parts and the partitions of n with parts that are either 1 or 4 modulo 5 have the same size. In their 1982 paper "A Roger-Ramanujan Bijection", Garsia and Milne proved that theorem with a bijection. The APL code for that bijection, which looks like a photocopy of a printout, is unfortunately unreadable. Has anyone implemented it in Mathematica?

Comment: What is your attempt? And please put related code here, for example, the APL code.

Comment: I have not made an attempt nor do I have any code.

Comment: Let me clarify that by unreadable, I mean that the photocopy of the APL code is partly illegible.

Comment: Well, are the authors still alive?

Comment: Oddly, that hadn't occurred to me. I emailed Stephen Milne. Thank you very much!